# Nickname cache issue

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I have plugin that use "ItemSend" event. Inside this event i'm creating copy of current email, changing one property(SendOnBehalf) and sending it, but current email i'm canceling. For user it looks like he just send his email. This functionality worked fine but in Outlook 2010-2013 Microsoft change some functionality and i discovered that when i'm creating email inside plugin and send it, email addresses of recipients stored in nicknamecache only util close Outlook. So after i close and Open Outlook nicknamecache don't have email addresses that was used before. So i found only one solution is use Redemption for write email addresses directly to nickname cache. I'm using following code:

```
    _session = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
    RedemptionLoader.DllLocation64Bit = string.Format("{0}\\redemption64.dll", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
    RedemptionLoader.DllLocation32Bit = string.Format("{0}\\redemption.dll", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

    _session.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);  

    var nicknames = session.GetNicknames();
    nicknames.Add(string.Format("{0} <{1}>", recip.Name, smtpAddress));
```

This code work fine in my PC but when i deploy it to test PC it fire error with message "MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND" when i'm calling

> nicknames.Add(string.Format("{0} <{1}>", recip.Name, smtpAddress));

I found that if i use

> nicknames.Add(string.Format("{0}", smtpAddress));

it works on test PC but give me error in my dev PC. Any ideas what can be wrong. Thank you for help

Comment: Have you tried to contact the Redemption developer?

Comment: What is the exact error? Redemption includes the offending method name along with the error code (MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND),